# How to resize the captured image in android

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap, adobecreativesdk, photoeditorsdk

When I am working on my Photo Editor Android application, after capturing the image from the camera through the app, I am resizing the image and then saving the image in the Gallery/Photos folder in the phone

Following is the HomeActivity code:

```
package com.saashtechs.photoeditor;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import static android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA;
import static android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
import static android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
import static android.content.pm.PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "HomeActivity";
    private static final int GALLERY_RESULT = 1;
    private static final int CAMERA_RESULT = 2;
    private static final String FILE_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY = "com.saashtechs.photoeditor";
    private static final int CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE = 1001;
    private static final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE = 1002;
    private Uri imageToUploadUri;
    private String mCapturedImagePath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    }

    public void openCamera(View view) {
        // check for camera permission if not granted before
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, CAMERA) != PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            String[] cameraPermission = {CAMERA};
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, cameraPermission, CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE);
        } else {
            dispatchImageCaptureIntent();
        }
    }

    public void openGallery(View view) {
        // check for storage permission if not granted before
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            String[] storagePermissions = {READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, storagePermissions, STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE);
        } else {
            dispatchGalleryIntent();
        }
    }

    private void dispatchGalleryIntent() {
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY_RESULT);
    }

    private void dispatchImageCaptureIntent() {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, FILE_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY, photoFile);
                Log.d(TAG, "dispatchImageCaptureIntent:photoFileUri: " + photoFile.toString());
                //Add URI to imageToUploadUri. You forgot to add it.
                imageToUploadUri = photoFileUri;
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoFileUri);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_RESULT);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE:
                if (grantResults[0] == PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    dispatchImageCaptureIntent();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Required camera permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;

            case STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE:
                if (grantResults[0] == PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    dispatchGalleryIntent();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Required storage permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
                break;

            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected request code");
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        String timeStamp = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
        mCapturedImagePath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        Log.d(TAG, "createImageFile: " + mCapturedImagePath);
        return image;
    }

    private Bundle uriToBundle(Uri imageUri) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(MainActivity.IMAGE_URI, imageUri.toString());
        return bundle;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == GALLERY_RESULT) {
                Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                startActivity(MainActivity.getIntent(this, uriToBundle(Objects.requireNonNull(imageUri))));
            } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_RESULT) {
                File imageFile = new File(mCapturedImagePath);
                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCapturedImagePath);
                image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, 300, 300, false);
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

                try {
                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "filename.jpg");
                    boolean result;
                    result = file.createNewFile();
                    if (result) {
                        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                        fo.close();
                    }
                } catch(IOException ie) {
                    ie.printStackTrace();
                }

                startActivity(MainActivity.getIntent(this, uriToBundle(Objects.requireNonNull(imageToUploadUri))));
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image not loaded.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public static Intent getIntent(Context context) {
        return new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
    }
}
```

manifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.saashtechs.photoeditor">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

  <application
      android:name="com.saashtechs.photoeditor.MainApplication"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:roundIcon="@drawable/app_icon"
      android:supportsRtl="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="com.saashtechs.photoeditor.MainActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.saashtechs.photoeditor.HomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme">
      <meta-data
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.com.saashtechs.photoeditor"
          android:value="@string/banner_id"/>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.saashtechs.photoeditor"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data
          android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
          android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
    </provider>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

So when I capture the image and then when the user is taken to edit the application, it doesn't, it takes me back to Home page again after capturing the image

Error log is:

```
2018-11-03 19:20:14.831 20452-20452/com.saashtechs.photoeditor E/AdobeImageEditorActivity: using a temporary file!
2018-11-03 19:20:15.565 21173-21248/? E/msgr.BootIdReader: Error reading boot_id from procfs
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id (Permission denied)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:200)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:150)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
        at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
        at X.1od.a(:322785)
        at X.482.a(:570546)
        at X.0JC.A(Unknown Source:26)
        at X.0Jl.a(:61297)
        at X.0Jl.b(:61321)
        at X.3RW.d(:485114)
        at X.3RW.b(:485105)
        at X.3RW.a(:485067)
        at X.3Wz.init(:500062)
        at X.0Pq.run(:76753)
        at X.0Or.run(:72967)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
        at X.0Q1.run(:77237)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at X.0MY.run(:67135)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at X.0Q3.run(:77257)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2018-11-03 19:20:15.980 21173-21235/? E/msgr.FDLeakDetector: Can only be constructed after a call to init()
2018-11-03 19:20:16.267 587-587/? E/SELinux: avc:  denied  { find } for interface=android.hardware.memtrack::IMemtrack pid=21173 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:hal_memtrack_hwservice:s0 tclass=hwservice_manager permissive=0
2018-11-03 19:20:16.268 21173-21273/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-11-03 19:20:16.486 21173-21278/? E/CompactDiskManagerImpl.cpp: Failed to remove new folder structure directories: No such file or directory
2018-11-03 19:20:16.779 21173-21257/? E/SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libreliability.so
2018-11-03 19:20:18.652 748-2390/? E/IzatSvc_ComboNetworkProvider: Exiting with error proc line 208 "1"
2018-11-03 19:20:20.948 3122-3304/? E/MarketManager: String array resource ID #0x0
2018-11-03 19:20:20.949 3122-3304/? E/MarketManager: String array resource ID #0x0
2018-11-03 19:20:20.958 3122-3304/? E/MarketManager: String array resource ID #0x0
2018-11-03 19:20:20.959 3122-3304/? E/MarketManager: String array resource ID #0x0
2018-11-03 19:20:20.965 3122-3304/? E/MarketManager: String array resource ID #0x0
2018-11-03 19:20:20.966 3122-3304/? E/MarketManager: String array resource ID #0x0
2018-11-03 19:20:20.973 3122-3304/? E/MarketManager: String array resource ID #0x0
2018-11-03 19:20:20.973 3122-3304/? E/MarketManager: String array resource ID #0x0
2018-11-03 19:20:21.009 3122-3304/? E/MarketManager: String array resource ID #0x0
2018-11-03 19:20:21.010 3122-3304/? E/MarketManager: String array resource ID #0x0
2018-11-03 19:20:21.012 3122-3304/? E/MarketManager: String array resource ID #0x0
2018-11-03 19:20:21.012 3122-3304/? E/MarketManager: String array resource ID #0x0
2018-11-03 19:20:21.014 3122-3304/? E/MarketManager: String array resource ID #0x0
2018-11-03 19:20:21.014 3122-3304/? E/MarketManager: String array resource ID #0x0
2018-11-03 19:20:21.015 3122-3304/? E/MarketManager: String array resource ID #0x0
2018-11-03 19:20:21.016 3122-3304/? E/MarketManager: String array resource ID #0x0
2018-11-03 19:20:22.469 18103-18147/? E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=20452, uid=10297 requires android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
        at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceWritePermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:713)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceWritePermission(ContentProvider.java:515)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:260)
        at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:152)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:702)
2018-11-03 19:20:22.486 20452-20452/com.saashtechs.photoeditor E/SaveHiResImageTask: save task cancelled

    --------- beginning of crash
2018-11-03 19:20:22.491 20452-21251/com.saashtechs.photoeditor E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
    Process: com.saashtechs.photoeditor, PID: 20452
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:353)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=20452, uid=10297 requires android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2005)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:476)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1555)
        at com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.internal.media.MediaUtils.insertImage(MediaUtils.java:36)
        at com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.AdobeImageEditorActivityAbstract$SaveHiResImageTask.doInBackground(AdobeImageEditorActivityAbstract.java:2004)
        at com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.AdobeImageEditorActivityAbstract$SaveHiResImageTask.doInBackground(AdobeImageEditorActivityAbstract.java:1905)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
2018-11-03 19:20:22.643 765-765/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/20452/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2018-11-03 19:20:22.814 2000-2136/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'b1f7fa com.saashtechs.photoeditor/com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.AdobeImageEditorActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2018-11-03 19:20:22.815 2000-2136/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'c744e87 com.saashtechs.photoeditor/com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.AdobeImageEditorActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2018-11-03 19:20:22.830 2000-2136/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '1ec9121 com.saashtechs.photoeditor/com.saashtechs.photoeditor.HomeActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2018-11-03 19:20:22.879 2000-3121/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedcom.miui.home/com.miui.home.launcher.Launcher/4053012
2018-11-03 19:20:22.880 751-809/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
2018-11-03 19:20:22.928 2406-21299/? E/NetworkScheduler: Invalid component specified.
```

Can you please tell me where am I going wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add in your onActivityResult

after:

```
image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, 300, 300, false);

image = resizeBitmap(image, 300);
```

you can change size to anySize u want

add this in you class: send bitmap and maximum size and get bitmap

```
public Bitmap resizeBitmap(Bitmap getBitmap, int maxSize) {
    int width = getBitmap.getWidth();
    int height = getBitmap.getHeight();
    double x;

    if (width >= height && width > maxSize) {
        x = width / height;
        width = maxSize;
        height = (int) (maxSize / x);
    } else if (height >= width && height > maxSize) {
        x = height / width;
        height = maxSize;
        width = (int) (maxSize / x);
    }
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(getBitmap, width, height, false);
}
```